# Checking strange item in dataset

Tags: python, data-science, data-cleaning

I wanna check strange categorical items in a dataframe with fewer lines in Python

I have tried to use the following codes to show the strange items.

```
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
  if data[data.columns[i]].dtype == "object":
    print(data[data.columns[i]].value_counts())
```

Is there any method using fewer lines to examine categorical data?

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by "strange"? Are you trying to remove outliers from data?

Comment: No. For example in the column of 'Sex', there might be only 'M' and 'F' but there might be also 'Boy' or 'Girl'. I wanna show them all and clean them. In R, I will use str(df) to show those factor objects. But I don't know how to do it in Python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all unique entries of a column I would recommend using `unique` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)) method

```
>>> a = pd.DataFrame({'sex':['m','f','m','m','m', 'f', 'booooy']})
>>> a.loc[:,'sex'].unique()
Out[1]: array(['m', 'f', 'booooy'], dtype=object)
```

To change `booooy` entry to `m` you can use `re.sub` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)) method

```
>>> a.loc[:,'sex'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'booooy','m', x))
Out[2]: 
0    m
1    f
2    m
3    m
4    m
5    f
6    m
Name: sex, dtype: object
```

If you have many `re.sub` calls - instead of applying them consequently you can put them into a function

```
>>> def filter_text(x):
...    x = re.sub(r'booooy','m',x)
...    x = re.sub(r'girl','f',x)
...    # . . . . . .
...    return x
>>> a.loc[:,'sex'].apply(filter_text)
Out[3]: 
0    m
1    f
2    m
3    m
4    m
5    f
6    m
Name: sex, dtype: object
```

Hope that helps!